# Delphi, Indy TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 gettin status code 403

Tags: delphi, ssl, http-status-code-403, indy, analyzer

i have one problem, that i dont know how to fix.
since few days i can't more login via indy to server (https://auth.bmwgroup.com, https://aos.bmwgroup.com, https://carver.bmwgroup.com).

TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 are enabled on this server.

So i started HttpAnalyzer to check where is the problem and my programm start to working, than i close HttpAnalyzer and my programm doesnt work anymore.

Can someone help to fix the problem.

i am using this code :

```
procedure TForm1.Server_NewInit;
var
    List: TStringList;
    URL, AuthID, ID_USER, ID_URL : AnsiString;
    JSON: TStringStream;
    l,p : string;
begin
    idHttpC := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    idHttpC.ConnectTimeout := 80000;
    idHttpC.ReadTimeout := 80000;
    idHttpC.AllowCookies := true;

// config Redirect's
    idHttpC.RedirectMaximum := 35;
    idHttpC.HandleRedirects := true;
    idHttpC.HTTPOptions := [hoKeepOrigProtocol, hoTreat302Like303];
    idHttpC.OnRedirect := IdHTTP1Redirect;

// create Cookie's
    idCookieC := TIdCookieManager.Create(IdHttpC);
    idHttpC.CookieManager := idCookieC;

// create OpenSSL
    lIOHandlerC := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    lIOHandlerC.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
    lIOHandlerC.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
    idHttpC.IOHandler := lIOHandlerC;

// Nr1 execute redirect
..
// Nr2 serverinfo
..
// Nr3 getSessionInfo
..
// Nr4 internetb2x empty post to get AuthId
..
// Nr5 internetb2x POST JSON - authorisation nr1
..
// Nr6 getSessionInfo after login
..
// check for authorisation give me ok, so, pass and login are ok
..
// Nr7 step idFromSession
..
// Nr8 step get info about user id
..
// Nr9 execute new ID_URL
..
// Nr10 authorisation Nr 2
idHttpC.Request.Referer := idHttpC.URL.GetFullURI([]);
idHttpC.Request.CacheControl := 'no-cache';
idHttpC.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
...
here i am getting problem
```

the steps from 1 to 9 working without any problem, i compare headers and content data, they are same as with launched analyzer.

but step nr10 give me with launched analyzer status

```
**RT HTTP/1.1 200 OK
RC 200
CT text/html**

Date: Mon, 22 Nov 2021 21:09:10 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Thu, 27 May 2021 09:09:24 GMT
ETag: "1b8-5c34c1d88f900"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=8640000; includeSubDomains
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
X-WebKit-CSP: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 440
refresh: 0; URL=/carver_www/carverMain.jsp
```

and without analyzer

```
**RT HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
RC 403
CT text/html** 

Date: Mon, 22 Nov 2021 21:10:20 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: accept-language,accept-charset
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=8640000; includeSubDomains
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
X-WebKit-CSP: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Language: de
```

**part2 :**

here request nr9

```
// prepare new Request for ID_URL
    idHttpC.Request.Clear;
    idHttpC.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
    idHttpC.Request.Accept := 'text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*';
    idHttpC.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'de-DE';
    idHttpC.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko';
    idHttpC.Request.Host := 'auth.bmwgroup.com';
    idHttpC.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Connection'] := 'Keep-Alive';
    idHttpC.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['DNT'] := '1';
    idHttpC.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate';

// Nr9 execute new ID_URL
    try
        res1 := idHttpC.Get(ID_URL);
        HTML_SaveToFile(res1, 'sFile9.txt');
        idHttpC.Response.RawHeaders.SaveToFile('RH9.txt');
    except
        on e:EIdSocketError do
            ShowMessage('EIdSocketError: ' + e.Message);
        on e:EIdReadTimeout do
            ShowMessage('EIdReadTimeout: ' + e.Message);
        on e:EIDHttpProtocolException do
            ShowMessage('EIDHttpProtocolException: ' + IntToStr(e.ErrorCode));
        on e:Exception do
            ShowMessage('Exception: ' + e.Message);
    end;
    Memo4.Lines.Add('Nr9 done');
```

with this request i got document :

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="OAuth 2.0 Form Post">
        <title>Submit This Form</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="javascript:document.forms[0].submit()">
        <form method="post" action="https://carver.bmwgroup.com:443/agent/cdsso-oauth2">
            <input type="hidden" name="id_token" value="...."/><input type="hidden" name="state" value="...."/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

this code i execute in step 10 :

```
// Nr10 authorisation Nr 2
    idHttpC.Request.Clear;
    idHttpC.Request.Accept := 'text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*';
    idHttpC.Request.Referer := idHttpC.URL.GetFullURI([]);
    idHttpC.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'de-DE';
    idHttpC.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko';
    idHttpC.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    idHttpC.Request.Host := 'carver.bmwgroup.com';
    idHttpC.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Connection'] := 'Keep-Alive';
    idHttpC.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['DNT'] := '1';
    idHttpC.Request.CacheControl := 'no-cache';
    idHttpC.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate';

    List := TStringList.Create;
    List.Add('id_token='+JSON_GET_ID(res1, 3, 0));
    List.Add('state='+JSON_GET_ID(res1, 4, 0));
    try
        res1 := idHttpC.Post('https://carver.bmwgroup.com/agent/cdsso-oauth2', List);
        FReeAndnil(List);
        Memo4.Lines.Add('RT' + idHttpC.Response.ResponseText);
        Memo4.Lines.Add('RC' + IntToStr(idHttpC.Response.ResponseCode));
        Memo4.Lines.Add('CT' + idHttpC.Response.ContentType);
        HTML_SaveToFile(res1, 'sFile10.txt');
        idHttpC.Response.RawHeaders.SaveToFile('RH10.txt');
    except
        on e:EIdSocketError do
            ShowMessage('EIdSocketError: ' + e.Message);
        on e:EIdReadTimeout do
            ShowMessage('EIdReadTimeout: ' + e.Message);
        on e:EIDHttpProtocolException do
            ShowMessage('EIDHttpProtocolException: ' + IntToStr(e.ErrorCode));
        on e:Exception do
            ShowMessage('Exception: ' + e.Message);
    end;
    Memo4.Lines.Add('Nr10 done');
```

Comment: It is really hard to diagnose this without seeing the actual HTTP request for step 10. But offhand, I don't see anything wrong with the code. There is a non-empty body present in the FORBIDDEN reply, does it say anything about why the request was rejected?

Comment: @RemyLebeau i added some code. I started Wireshark and the code don't work, than i start HttpAnalyzer on pause, the code working fine, i stop logging in HttpAnalyzer the code don't work.

Comment: @RemyLebeau if you like i can send you this "working code" via email. P.S. ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll are both 1.0.2u

Comment: you did not answer my question. What does the body content of the 403 response actually say? You also haven't shown any of the raw HTTP request headers/data. For instance, are cookies being sent back to the server correctly, especially on step 10? In any case, I don't see any real problems with your code (though I do see some mistakes, but they are not related to your issue), so the issue has to be elsewhere. BTW, why are you using a JSON parser to extract values from HTML?

Comment: @RemyLebeau i got it, i dont know why, but i deleted my Compressor from procedure. After i added it, its works. What is the best way to get values from URI or html body? and which mistakes did you find, i really want to know it, to learn more.

Comment: nothing in the code you showed indicated a `Compressor` was being used, however assigning `Request.AcceptEncoding` is almost always a mistake, unless you are prepared to manually decompress/decode the response body. Otherwise, don't assign `AcceptEncoding` at all, let `TIdHTTP` manage that internally. Other mistakes I see: 1) assigning `Request.Host`, let `TIdHTTP` manage that. 2) assigning to `Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Connection']`, should be assigning to `Request.Connection` instead. 3) calling `Request.CustomHeaders.Clear()` after `Request.Clear()` is redundant.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you very much i updated my code. But after i execute Request.Clear() there is still some CustomHeaders like 'Accept-API-Version','X-Password','X-Username','X-NoSession'. i can delete it only if i execute Request.CustomHeaders.Clear(). P.S. What is the best way to get values from URI or html body?

Comment: "*after i execute Request.Clear() there is still some CustomHeaders*" - interesting, I wouldn't have expected that. That is probably a bug that needs fixing.

Comment: "*That is probably a bug that needs fixing*' - It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on step nr9, where i got in indy compressed data :

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Why the code was working with httpAnalyzer ? Because httpAnalyzer logging network protocol via owned library and in this case httpAnalyzer decompress data for me.

after i added

```
idHttpC.Compressor := TIdCompressorZLib.Create(idHttpC);
```

the code work again.

Comment: The real problem is that you manually set `idHttpC.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate';` to begin with. By setting that, you told the server that you accept compressed data, *even if you really don't*. By assigning the `TIdHTTP.Compressor`, it can then decompress data automatically. Either way, you should not set `Request.AcceptEncoding` manually at all, let `TIdHTTP` set it internally for you based on its available capabilities. Had you not assigned `Request.AcceptEncoding` manually, and did not have a `Compressor` assigned, `TIdHTTP` would not ask the server for compressed data...

Comment: ... but even with a `Compressor` assigned, there is still no guarantee that compressed data can actually be decompressed automatically (check the `TIdCompressorZLib.IsReady` property), in which case you *still* should not set `Request.AcceptEncoding` manually. If the `Compressor` is ready, `TIdHTTP` will internally update `Request.AcceptEncoding` to enable `gzip, deflate` to assk for compression. But if you leave `Request.AcceptEncoding` blank, and the `Compressor` is not ready, `TIdHTTP` will not update `Request.AcceptEncoding`, and so compressed data will not be asked for.

Answer (score 1):

#### Authorization

Out of curiosity I googled bmwgroup api. From a quick scan I saw that the API requires passing a bearer token. I don't see you passing that.

Usually you first obtain the token via a first call. In your description you write that that part works, so I guess you have your token somewhere as received in a previous step.

It's a header that should probably look like this:
`Authorization: Bearer xxx`, where xxx is your token.

Or at least you did not paste any code where you have that.

#### Faster debugging

Anyway, debugging Delphi code when you run into stuff like this can be difficult and slow.

What I usually do is grab something like Postman or use a JetBrains IDE and create a .http file (I've seen people use .http files from VSCode as well).

I tweak my requests until I can make it work "manually". Then I work my way backwards to create Delphi code that does the same.
That approach is usually much faster than updating pascal code, compile, run, wait for a breakpoint to hit, check what's happening in the debugger, etc.

Comment: the problem was in step 9, where i got `Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Encoding: gzip`. in my procedure i didn't assign Compressor to indy, so got compressed data and can't extract token and state to send it in step 10.

Comment: @EvgenyLevitskiy: So is it working now?

Comment: Yes, now its work. `idHttpC.Compressor := TIdCompressorZLib.Create(idHttpC);`